# Is it possible to change the text color of one UILabel out of my for loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, uilabel

I have a `for` loop to get 7 UILabel inside a UIStackView.

Everything works perfectly (so my question seems ridiculous) but I would like to find a way to change the color of the UILabel out to my `for` loop.

I need to change the color of the second label only, not all of them.

```
-(void)setupView {

    UIStackView *stack = UIStackView.new;
    stack.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
    stack.spacing = 1;
    stack.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillEqually;
    stack.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentFill;
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addSubview:stack];

    [stack.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [stack.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [stack.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    [stack.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:60].active = YES;

    for (NSInteger v = 0; v <= 30; v++) {
        UIView *container = UIView.new;
        container.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [self valueLbl];

        _valueLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long) v];
        _valueLbl.tag = v;
        [container addSubview:_valueLbl];
        [_valueLbl.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:container.centerYAnchor]
        [_valueLbl.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:container.centerXAnchor].active = YES;

        [stack addArrangedSubview:container];
    }

}

-(void)changeValueLabelColor {
    // Change color of UILabel number 1 of 7

    if (_valueLbl.tag == 1) _valueLbl.textColor = UIColor.redColor;
    else _valueLbl.textColor = UIColor.blackColor;
}
```

In the `changeValueLabelColor` method I am trying to change the color of the label with tag 1 (outside the FOR loop) but this does not work .. Only the last label changes color and not the first .. I need it to change only the first and the others they must remain the same ...

I need to be able to freely access each of the labels created with the for loop, using another method

I tried to assign `label.tag` but it doesn't work. How can I fix it? Can I solve it any other way?

Comment: you need a reference to the variable to change its properties.

Comment: I need change color only one label... I'm edited my question ... sorry

Comment: `if (v == 1)`...?

Comment: @matt out of for circle?  in another method ?

Comment: Show what you actually tried. And clearly define "doesn't work". In what way didn't it work exactly? What is `[self valueLbl]` doing? Why are you reusing `_valueLbl` inside the loop?

Comment: @rmaddy I changed my question ... I hope I could explain myself well

Comment: Once the loop is done, `_valueLbl` is only pointing to the last label (with a tag of 30).

Comment: @rmaddy yes I had understood this ... I was wondering if it is possible to find a way (even different) to be able to solve my problem ...

Answer (score -1):

Just store a reference (assign a property) to a label you need and change its textColor when you need. However, you can access your labels via `arrangedSubviews` property of `UIStackView`.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood myself .. sorry ... I will change my question .. I need to change the color of the second label only, not all of them

Comment: @kAiN Than the proper way to do it is to store a reference to than label (via private @property) or access it with [stack.arrangedSubviews objectAtIndex: 1]

Comment: I already have a uilabel property (_valueLbl) that I use in the for loop ... but in another method it just keeps changing the last label created by the FOR loop .. I don't understand why